# Поворот графика в amCharts 4

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

После перехода на новую версию, столкнулся с проблемой поворота графика на 90 градусов. В версии amCharts3 можно было сделать одной строкой `"rotation": true`.
Ниже приведу код.

Внимание, вопрос: **Как повернуть данный график на 90 градусов?** Какие строки надо дописать?

Единственное вычитал, не смог применить `categoryAxis.` класс `Sprites` и его атрибут `rotation (0-360)`
Заранее благодарю!

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dark);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in

chart.data = [
  {
    country: "USA",
    visits: 23725
  },
  {
    country: "Canada",
    visits: 441
  }
];

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 24000;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
// axis break
var axisBreak = valueAxis.axisBreaks.create();
axisBreak.startValue = 2100;
axisBreak.endValue = 22900;
axisBreak.breakSize = 0.005;

// make break expand on hover
var hoverState = axisBreak.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.breakSize = 1;
hoverState.properties.opacity = 0.1;
hoverState.transitionDuration = 1500;

axisBreak.defaultState.transitionDuration = 1000;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
series.columns.template.tooltipY = 0;
series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;

// as by default columns of the same series are of the same color, we add adapter which takes colors from chart.colors color set
series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

body { background-color: #30303d; color: #fff; }
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dark.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось довольно интересно:
Надо заменить fабсолютно все упоминания оси X на ось Y и наоборот.
(внимание на символы X Y)

Было:

```
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
```

Стало:

```
var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
series.dataFields.categoryY = "country";
```